# What is the difference between using weight decay in an optimizer and weight decay in neural network layers?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, regularized, overfitting-underfitting

What distinguishes the utilization of weight decay in an optimizer from weight decay applied to neural network layers? Let's examine this through an example:

```
%%%% ipt is our input matrix.
weight_decay = 1e-4
x     =  LSTM(12, kernel_regularizer = l2(weight_decay), bias_regularizer = l2(weight_decay))(ipt)
out   = Dense(1, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer = l2(weight_decay), bias_regularizer = l2(weight_decay))(x)
dl_model = Model(ipt, out)
dl_model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001, decay = 1e-5), loss = 'mse')
```

The initial utilization of weight decay involves applying L2 regularizer (both bias and kernel), while the second one is within the context of the Adam optimizer (`decay` parameter). What are the primary distinctions between these two approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L2 regularization on weights directly influences the *model's architecture* by penalizing the magnitude of weights in each layer to prevent overfitting.

The Adam optimizer's decay parameter *controls the learning rate scheduling* and does not directly regularize the model's weights. It is used to fine-tune the optimization process.

Both techniques can be preferred to train models, but they serve different purposes in the training process. Weight regularization like L1 and L2, is a form of explicit constraint on the model's weights, while learning rate scheduling (Adam's decay) is a method for controlling the optimization process during training.

Also, the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29130/difference-between-neural-net-weight-decay-and-learning-rate) can be reviewed for mathematical expression.